# Unexpected recurrence of Python unicode string ascii codec error

Tags: python, encoding

After days and months of desperation I recently found a solution to overcome the infamous `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec cant encoe character u'\u2026' in position 18: ordinal not in range (128)`. It was dealing with multilingual strings pretty well until recently, I bumped into this error AGAIN!

I tried `type(thatstring)` and it returned Unicode.
So I tried:

```
thatstring=thatstring.decode('utf-8')
```

This was handling those multilanguage strings pretty well but it came back now. I also tried

```
thatstring=thatstring.decode('utf-8','ignore')
```

No use.

```
thatstring=thatstring.encode('utf-8','ignore')
```

bounces with the error 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec cant decode byte 0xc3 in position 48: ordinal not in range (128)` faster than its counterpart.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You probably do well to post `thatstring`. This issue is a special character somewhere in `thatstring` that's not being encoded properly, so it would probably help to see the string that it's occurring in. Even better is if you can narrow it down to just the word or character that's erroring and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the right thing by trying `type(thatstring)`, but you didn't draw the right conclusion from the result.

A unicode string has *already been decoded*, so trying to decode it again will produce an error if it contains non-ascii characters. When you use `decode()` on a unicode object, you effectively force python to do something like this:

```
temp = thatstring.encode('ascii') # convert unicode to bytes first
thatstring = temp.decode('utf-8') # now decode bytes back to unicode
```

Obviously, the first line will blow up as soon as it finds a non-ascii character, which explains why you see a unicode **encode** error, even though you are trying to **decode** the string. So the simple answer to your problem is: don't do that!

Instead, whenever your program receives string inputs, and wants to make sure they're converted to unicode, it should do something like this:

```
if isinstance(thatstring, bytes):
    thatstring = thatstring.decode(encoding)
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation. Works. :)